# How can I prevent the administrator password prompts?

Tags: macos

When deleting files, installing new applications, running AppleScript code, etc, I am prompted to enter my administrator password:

[image: Administator Prompt]

How can I set it so that everything I do is authorized to where it doesn't require a password?

**Note**: I'm running OS X Yosemite v10.10.5 (14F27).

Comment: It is for your protection, like seatbelt in the car.

Comment: How often are you being prompted?  I know it can a bit annoying however it's for your own good, as every user is their own worst enemy especially when wanting to subvert security measures.

Comment: Quite often. I'd estimate around 100 in the last hour. @user3439894

Comment: Sounds like something is seriously wrong.  You might want to elaborate a bit more on things. The only time I've had anywhere near that number of prompts was when I first built out my system and installed close to that number of programs.  However with day-to-day every day use the number of prompts is negligible in comparison although appropriate for thing that I might be doing.

Comment: Generally the prompts appear when I'm cleaning up files from all of other accounts. @user3439894

Comment: You've got some nice general answers. If you want to narrow things down, why not ask a second follow up question. The answer how to get AppleScript not to prompt is different than the answer to avoid having other user files pop a prompt is different from app installations. It would be best to explain what app installation is causing this - then we can answer exactly without guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**root** user](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204012). This is highly unrecommended, but it will never show you an administrator privileges dialog.

Comment: Useful information and something I'll keep in mind, but is this the *only* way? I would much prefer to use my personal account.

Comment: @ZachGates I don't believe there is any other way. Apple sets this as an impassable security feature

Answer (score 1):

*This method does work, but I'm not sufficient a nix guru to know if there could be unforeseen side effects, so a) proceed with caution & b) if anyone knows better or has useful caveats, please let us know.*

You could set the permissions to group `wheel` instead of `admin` or `staff`, then add yourself to the `wheel` group if you're not already a member.

The `wheel` group historically behaves like `admin` or `staff` but doesn't require a password if you are a member of it. It also is not an automatic addition when setting up a new admin account, it must be conferred manually.

You can test on the root level of the boot drive, as that's one place where creating or deleting a file will always ask for your password if group is set to admin or staff, rather than wheel.
*Don't recklessly 'Apply to enclosed'.*

I find [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/)'s GUI interface easy to understand & simpler to use than terminal.
Horizontal lines mean 'no change'. This will preserve existing ownership & Everyone perms whilst changing the group permissions in the example below.
Apply to enclosed will recursively change all the contents of your chosen folder, so use with extreme care.

[image]

to check what groups you are already in, use Terminal
`id myname`
You should already be in admin & staff, amongst others.

If you're not already a member of wheel
`sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership myname`
which will request your password & add you to that group. Test again with `id myname`

This appears to require a relog before the system recognises the change.

Comment: Downvote with no explanation, on an answer I was asking for confirmation/correction/clarification on? Really?? With great power comes great responsibility...oh, no, sorry, it doesn't, this is the interweb.

Answer (score 0):

Apple actually gives you fined grained control over what requires admin prompt using the security authorizationdb command. 
See https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/managing-the-authorization-database-in-os-x-mavericks/

Authbuddy also is also a 3rd party tool that is supposed to make this easier http://www.dssw.co.uk/authbuddy/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please add the relevant information or description of functions from the links you added. [Link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and may get downvoted / deleted.